# Issues with cross-browsing

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge

I have a website that displays differently on Safari, Mozilla, Edge and IE.
On Mozilla and IE my select tags shows a different style.

CSS:

```
.soflow, select#soflow-color {
   -webkit-appearance: button;
   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
   -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   background-image: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 40%, #E5E5E5);
   background-position: 97% center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border: 1px solid #AAA;
   color: #555;
   font-size: 11px;
   margin: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 2px 6px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 180px;
   float: left;
}
```

What I'm getting on those browsers:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

And on Safari and Edge `document.getElementById("id").style.display='';` and `document.getElementById("id").style.display='none';` are not recognized.

How can I fix this?
Any help will be appreaciated!

Comment: `-webkit-padding-end` and `-webkit-padding-start` get overwritten when you set a value via `padding` after `-webkit-padding` has been declared.

Comment: So what do I have to do?

Comment: Lookup `custom styled select`. The approach I've seen is that you strip down the default styling of the `<select>` as much as possible with CSS (the down arrow it tough to style cross browser), then wrap the select in a `<div>` that you style as if it was the `<select>`.